# Tracking events inside a Google Visualization API request

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

This is the snippet I'm using to retrieve a table from a Google Sheet using the Google Visualization API.

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['table']
});

var visualization;

function drawVisualization() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=XXXXXXXX&hl=it_IT');
    query.setQuery('SELECT B, C, D, E, F, G, H where upper(B) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or upper(D) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or upper(F) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") order by G DESC label G "Data"');
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();

    var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat(
        '<a href="{6}" target="_blank" onclick="var that=this;_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\',\'Event Category\',{2},this.href]);setTimeout(function(){location.href=that.href;},200);return false;">{2}</a>');
    // Apply formatter and set the formatted value of the first column.
    formatter.format(data, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([2, 0, 1, 4, 5]); // Create a view with the first column only.

    visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
    visualization.draw(view, {
        legend: 'bottom',
        allowHtml: true
    });

}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

As you can see, I'm trying to track the download triggering a Javascript event onclick.

```
<a href="URL" target="_blank" onclick="var that=this;_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','EVENT_CATEGORY','EVENT_URL',this.href]);setTimeout(function(){location.href=that.href;},200);return false;">LINK_NAME</a>
```

This code works if used in a "normal" page (i.e. the event is tracked in Google Analytics), but it doesn't work here (I presume because it's inside an iframe?).
Is there a workaround to be able to track the event?

Comment: Does the iframe have GA tracking enabled?

Comment: The iframe is the Google Sheet's table loaded from Google. I don't have access to it

Comment: Then it won't be possible to track anything in the iframe at all. You need to include your GA tracking code on that page in order do any tracking.

Comment: Isn't this something I could use? https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events?hl=en#the-select-event

Answer (score 0):

You can set up tracking for an iframe with Google Analytics if you can include the GA tracking code in the iframe and (if the iframe is from a different domain) if you attach cross-domain tracking code in the iframe, linking the two domains together. From the sounds of it you will not be able to track this.

Also keep in mind that an iframe on a page without tracking in the iframe will count as a bounce, since you are loading your page, then google fires, then google will think you are leaving because you are loading a separate domain.

One solution could be to try and build you own button outside the iframe that will trigger a download of the chart (by effectively requesting it again with a image mimetype). You could track that. It would not necessarily get 100% of clicks but at least some (i.e. the people who click the button, not the iframe).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The problem is that the iframe is generated by the Google Visualization API, I don't think I can add my own code in it...

Comment: If you don't have control over the iframe I'm afraid there is nothing you can do to track that.